# psycopg2 connect problem，can't select column , but connection is ok

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.6, psycopg2

I connected the db by psycopg2.But can't select the column,use "select *" is ok.

```
import psycopg2
db = psycopg2.connect(host='ip',port='port',user='user', password='pw', 
database='basdw')
print("Opened database successfully")
cur = db.cursor()
query = "SELECT UVCOOKIE FROM bas_appcvevent LIMIT 10"
cur.execute(query)
data = cur.fetchall()
print(data)
db.close()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 24, in 
    cur.execute(query)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError:

> column "uvcookie" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT UVCOOKIE FROM
>   bas_appcvevent LIMIT 10

but uvcookie is exist in the table.If I use "select *",it's ok.

```
import psycopg2
db = psycopg2.connect(host='ip',port='port',user='user', password='pw', 
database='basdw')
print("Opened database successfully")
cur = db.cursor()
query = "SELECT UVCOOKIE FROM bas_appcvevent LIMIT 10"
cur.execute(query)
data = cur.fetchall()
print(data)
db.close()
```

**output:**

```
[(121, 1494990395269, None, 0, None, 0, 'j1wb5963_6_6_34_CA5F6F05-5273-4107-A1A2-3F98DE7DCA88', .....]
```

Answer (score 0):

can you show the output of `\d bas_appcvevent` Postgresql makes no difference between uppercase and lowercase so even if you type:

```
SELECT UVCOOKIE FROM bas_appcvevent LIMIT 10;
```

postresql does:

```
SELECT uvcookie FROM bas_appcvevent LIMIT 10;
```

If the column name is actually in uppercase then use double quotes like this:

```
SELECT "UVCOOKIE" FROM bas_appcvevent LIMIT 10;
```